# How to mock overloaded public static method which returns void with PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, static, void, powermockito

I got a problem mocking a public static method which returns void, when I want it to throw specific Exception (e.g. RuntimeException)

This is what I have so far:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TheUtilsClass.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void theTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TheUtilsClass.class);
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException.class).when(TheUtilsClass.class, "methodToBeMocked", any(FirstParam.class), any(SecondParam.class));
    }
}
```

And this does not work because "methodToBeMocked" is overloaded several times. Instead I got the exception **TooManyMethodsFoundException** where I could not suppress other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution myself, but could not find it online. Actually I just have created an Answer which throws the needed exception and that's it:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TheUtilsClass.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void theTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TheUtilsClass.class, new Answer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```